# Insert multiple data in one single database row

Tags: php

I have code for uploading multiple images, it is returning the word `"ARRAY"`, not return the content when I make `" echo , die;"`, and in the other ways it return just the first upload and inserted into database.

I want to insert multiple value `"IMGE"` in single row database.

Controller:

```
function uploadFile(){

    $data = array();
    // If file upload form submitted
    if($this->input->post('Submit') && !empty($_FILES['files']['name']))
    {
        $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
            $_FILES['file']['name']     = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type']     = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error']     = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size']     = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];

            // File upload configuration
            $uploadPath = 'uploads/files/';
            $config['upload_path'] = $uploadPath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';

            // Load and initialize upload library
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            // Upload file to server
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                // Uploaded file data

                ///////////////////////////////////////////
             //HERR I WANT TO RETURN THE  -  $file[$i]  - WITH ALL
             //THE IMAGE UPLAD TO INSER IN SINGLE ROW IN DATABASE
             ///////////////////////////////////////////    
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $uploadData[$i]['file_name'] = $fileData['file_name'];
                $uploadData[$i]['uploaded_on'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $file[$i] = $uploadData[$i]['file_name']; 
                return $file[$i];
                echo $file[$i]  , die; // here it is just return first image upload 


            }

        }

        if(!empty($uploadData)){

           return $uploadData;
           echo $new_array, die;// here it is  return word "ARRAY"}}
```

Model:

```
function insert_data($data) // from one table 
{  
      $insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_reservations', $data);
}
```

Comment: Word `Array` is a string representation of php array.

Comment: use `print_r($newArray)` instead of `echo`

Comment: Try `var_dump($new_array);` or `print_r($new_array);` instead. You cannot echo an array like you do a string.

Comment: when i remove , and try to click submit function , it show to me this Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' INSERT INTO tbl_reservations (visittype, date, time, reasons, symptoms, doctor_id, user_id, file_name) VALUES ('Online', '2018-09-17', NULL, '979', '07', '76', '76', Array) Filename: models/Reservation_model.php Line Number: 60 –

Comment: this is the erre messsge screen shot https://a.top4top.net/p_9905ch5v1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert an array o DB field, you have to loop throw it.

```
function insert_data($data) // from one table 
{  
    // I suppose that $data is multi dimensional array that conatins single 'row' on each item
    foreach($data as $item){
       $insert = $this->db->insert('tbl_reservations', $item);
    } 
}
```

### EDIT 2

Ok now i figured out the problem. Tha data array passed to `insert_data` contains an array with all file names.

REPLACE your `insert()` whith the below code:

```
public function insert(){ 
    $uploadedFiles = $this->uploadFile(); // returns the file names array 

    // Map post data to table field
    $data = array(
       'visittype' => $this->input->post('visittype'),
       'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
       'time' => $this->input->post('time'),
       'reasons' => $this->input->post('reasons'),
       'symptoms' => $this->input->post('symptoms'),
       'doctor_id' => $this->input->post('doctorid'),
       'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('doctor')[0]->user_id
    );        

    // Loop on file names and insert each one on the db row.
    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $file){ 
        $data['file_name'] = $file['file_name'];
        $this->Reservation_model->insert_data($data); 
    }
}
```

This way yuo will have as many rows as the uploaded file. If you want to have only one row that contains all files you have to store them as json string and decode when needed.

### EDIT 3

uploadedFiles() returns something like this:

```
$uploadedFiles = [
    ['file_name' => 'file_one.jpg'],
    ['file_name' => 'file_two.jpg'],
    ['file_name' => 'file_three.jpg']
];
```

you can't store an array on a DB row field.

I can suggest you two ways:

1 - Create a Master/Detail structure. `tbl_reservations` to store master data, the current one and `tbl_reservations_files` to store file names for each reservation.

2 - Store file name as string, like CSV.

This is the code for solution 2:

```
public function insert(){
    $uploadedFiles = $this->uploadFile(); // returns the file names array

    // Map post data to table field
    $data = array(
        'visittype' => $this->input->post('visittype'),
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
        'time' => $this->input->post('time'),
        'reasons' => $this->input->post('reasons'),
        'symptoms' => $this->input->post('symptoms'),
        'doctor_id' => $this->input->post('doctorid'),
        'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('doctor')[0]->user_id
    );

    // Reduce file list as a CSV string
    $data['file_name'] = array_reduce($uploadedFiles, function ($carry, $item) { 
        // $carry is the value from previews iteration, $item is current array item. see array_reduce on php doc for more.
        // ',' can be replaced with any char of your need
        return $carry . ($carry === '' ?: ',') . $item['file_name'];
    }, '');

    // Insert data on DB
    $this->Reservation_model->insert_data($data);
}
```

Comment: in this case i have this erer https://c.top4top.net/p_990xxhkx1.png  , he make the "value of visittype coulm ' as the culom name , and he search in data for colum "Online"

Comment: the form has also many fild to insert into database , not just the "image "  so what i have to do ???

Comment: can you please do a `print_r($data); die;` before the `foreach` loop? than post the output.

Comment: and the foreach in the modal , i deleted? or ?

Comment: i made your EDIT , but i fi but forech in MODEL i get this https://c.top4top.net/p_990xxhkx1.png  - AND if i delet the foreach form MODEL i get this https://a.top4top.net/p_9905ch5v1.png

Comment: can you please post both functions code, controller and model. I need to see the complete code to provide a better solution. thanks.

Comment: Controller:   https://b.top4top.net/p_990bqtfl1.png   -   https://d.top4top.net/p_99015goo3.png   -     Model: 
  https://c.top4top.net/p_990oci732.png   -

Comment: please check EDIT 2

Comment: ya , it work , but not what i aculy want , i want all in one row ... but TNHANKS ,
Thank you u have made your effort with me beautifully *-^

Comment: I made another edit, please let me know if it was useful to you, if so accept my solution. Thank you.

Comment: show this Message: array_reduce() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given. i will try the sulotion 1 for new database tabel , i will try at the night and tell u

Comment: The Problem Solved By Create New DataBase File  , fisrt Table form my data , and the second for the file , each file insert with the fisrt id , so that whay i can insert and retrive form data by id .. thanks for mension me to this idea

Answer (score 1):

The die function prints a message and exits the current script, for this reason only the first file is inserted .so remove die .

Comment: when i remove , and try to click submit function , it show to me this Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list' INSERT INTO tbl_reservations (visittype, date, time, reasons, symptoms, doctor_id, user_id, file_name) VALUES ('Online', '2018-09-17', NULL, '979', '07', '76', '76', Array) Filename: models/Reservation_model.php Line Number: 60 –

Comment: this is the erre messsge screen shot https://a.top4top.net/p_9905ch5v1.png

Comment: how do you call the function insert_data in your code ?? 
because the function didn't  know  the variable Array

Comment: code insert screeen shot http://a.up-00.com/2018/09/153719003649161.png

Comment: $file_name  : is  array  so try with this : data= array{ 'doctor_id'=>$doctorid,'file_name', $file_name['file']['name']}

Comment: print_r($file_name) and send   screen shot for the result

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 echo $new_array, die;// here it is  return word "ARRAY"}}
```

To

```
print_r($new_array);
```

As `$new_array` is array, you need to print array using `print_r` or `var_dump`. Using echo will show Array as it is an array. Also don't use die, it will stop script and you won't be able to insert second image.

Comment: when i remove , and try to click submit function , it show to me this   Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `tbl_reservations` (`visittype`, `date`, `time`, `reasons`, `symptoms`, `doctor_id`, `user_id`, `file_name`) VALUES ('Online', '2018-09-17', NULL, '979', '07', '76', '76', Array)

Filename: models/Reservation_model.php

Line Number: 60

Comment: this is the erre messsge screen shot https://a.top4top.net/p_9905ch5v1.png